# Surname into AD not working with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I recently found out that i have a problem, the problem is in powershell. Ill explain first. When in Excel a surname is empty or it has a / or - in it it won't go into AD. But it also happens with 2 ordinary names without a - / or being empty.

[Here is a picture of an empty surname which wont add into AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS2kk.png)

[Here is a picture with an ordinary subname which wont be added and one with an -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceBkA.png)

Other normal names have been added to my AD, but these don't.

```
$accountname = $_.Volledigenaam #third row in excel (Given and surname combined)
$givenName = $_.Voornaam #first row in excel
$surname = $_.Achternaam #second row in excel
if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $accountname})
    {
        Write-Warning "Already existing name $accountname."
    }
else
    {
        new-aduser -name $_.Volledigenaam -displayName $_.Volledigenaam -enabled $true –givenName $givenName –surname $surname -Path "ou=Users,ou=NLHKH,dc=CONTOSO,dc=com" -accountpassword (convertto-securestring "PassW0rd!" -asplaintext -force) -changepasswordatlogon $true -samaccountname $accountname –userprincipalname ($accountname+”@ad.contoso.com”) 
    }
}
```

***The name provided is not a properly formed account name, is the error i get***

As you can see here is my code ^^

Comment: Is mixing current object on pipeline, `$_`, and explicit variables such as `$accountname` intentional?

Comment: No thats not intentional in my new code i have the ```ned-aduser -name $accountname```

Comment: Then please [edit] the question so that if it doesn't contain `-name $_.Volledigenaam`, change it to whatever the code actually is. Use copy-paste to avoid typos. It's likely to be `new-aduser` instead of `ned-aduser`. This is important, as the error might be caused by a spelling mistake and the only way to catch those is to be very carful.

Comment: i have found the problem. u cant use special chars and cant exceed a limit of 20 but anyhow thanks for your responses!